# Replacing or Deleteing a page in History

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am currently developing an app that has a login, after the person logs in I want to remove the login page from history so that if they choose the back button (after login) it wont go back to the login page, but the one before it.

In javascript the code is `location.replace('whatever_url_you_are_forwarding_to');` I want to know the equivalent in Java / JSF

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for server-side Java code to modify the history of the client-side browser. 
I wouldn't mess with the browser history: users expect a consistent and predictable behavior for the back button. If they want to go back to the login page, let them go back to the login page.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, it was in my mind as a security breach to be able to do this, but if I set my beans right, I should be OK

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this the following way:

- Tell the browser to not cache the login page, so that it will always send a fullworthy GET request on it instead of loading from the browser cache.
- When the login page is requested while the user is already logged-in, then send a redirect to the desired page (which you've remembered in the session when the user logs in).

This could be done in one and same [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) (although I'd personally prefer to disable browser caching on all change-sensitive dynamic pages, so that would then be done in another filter on a more generic URL pattern covering those pages).

Here's a kickoff example assuming that you're using container managed authentication (for homegrown authentication wherein you manually put the user in the session, just check the presence of the session attribute instead):

```
@WebFilter("/login.xhtml")
public class LoginPageFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        // Tell browser to not cache this page.
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

        // Check if user is logged in.
        if (request.getRemoteUser() == null) {
            // Not logged in, so remember previous URL and continue request.
            session.setAttribute("referrer", request.getHeader("referer")); // Yes, the misspelling is "correct"!
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } 
        else {
            // Logged in, so redirect to initial referring URL, if any.
            String referrer = (String) session.getAttribute("referrer");

            if (referrer != null) {
                response.sendRedirect(referrer);
            }
            else {
                // There was no referring page. Just continue request?
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, just have to get my head around what you have done, you are more advanced than me, so this will need some analysing. I am not sure about the "container managed authentication (for homegrown authentication wherein you manually put the user in the session, just check the presence of the session attribute instead", can you explain that a bit, or tell me where it can be explaind

Comment: How are you doing user authentication? Since you never heard of container managed authentication, I'll assume that you're just manually handling authentication by putting the logged-in user in the session and letting your application intercept on its presence?

Comment: thanks again, Pretty well, user is read from a MySQL Database, depending on their level, they get access to 
the rest of the site or to the admin section, where they can update a database, all set with sessions

Comment: Just replace `if (request.getRemoteUser() == null)` by `if (session.getAttribute("user") == null)` then, at least the usual way how you check if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Hey I sort of figured out simply how to do this, now I have a new prob, here is the code  
    <p:commandButton  
        ajax="#{true}"  
        actionListener="#{loginBean.logout}"  
        onsuccess="location.replace('/MainPage')"  
        style="width: 200px;"  
        title="Logout" value="Logout"/>
      
problem now its not calling the listener, any ideas ?

Comment: Make sure that it's in its own `<h:form>`. Also, you don't want to logout by ajax. You don't want to use `actionListener`. You don't need that nonsensicial JS `onsuccess` approach. Just point to a normal `action` method which invalidates the session and returns `"MainPage?faces-redirect=true"`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried this approach but  the page where I logging out from, stays in the history eg: User logs in and is moved to admin page, user logs out from admin page and "theoretically" moved back to home page and admin page is no longer in history. The solution I provided achieves this but it won't call any action or actionListeners ??